# Convert a decimal number to hexadecimal and binary in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, binary, hex

I have a decimal number in each line of a `file.txt`:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

I am trying (for too long now) to write a one-liner script to have an output where each row has a column with the decimal, hexadecimal and the binary. To ease the task we can say that the original number is expressed in a byte. So the maximum value is 255.

1. I first try to decode each number as a bynary with prepended 0 so to have an 8 bits pattern:

   `awk '{print "ibase=10;obase=2;" $1}' $1 | bc | xargs printf "%08d\n"`

   where the outer $1 in the awk statement is `file.txt`. The output is :

   ```
   00000001
   00000010
   00000011
   ```
2. Same for hex with one prepended 0

   `awk '{printf("0x%02x\n", $1)}' $1`

   Same as before. The Output is :

   ```
   0x01
   0x02
   0x03
   ```
3. Well, the decimal should be just a print:

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   ```

What I'd like to have is one liner where I have:

```
    1 00000001 0x01
    2 00000001 0x02
```

so basically to put 1. 2. and 3. in each line of the output.

I tried to execute bc (and other command) within awk using system() without success. And a zillion other ways. What is the way you would do it?

Comment: For hexadecimal you can use: `printf "%X" 15` it returns `F`.

Comment: @fedorqui I want an hexadecimal number expressed as with a fixed width. Thus I choose 0x%02x where %02x means two digit (Or so I believe). Capital X will only make it uppercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following one-liner should work:

```
printf "%s %08d 0x%02x\n" "$1" $(bc <<< "ibase=10;obase=2;$1") "$1"
```

Example output:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do printf "%s %08d 0x%02x\n" "$i" $(bc <<< "ibase=10;obase=2;$i") "$i"; done
1 00000001 0x01
2 00000010 0x02
3 00000011 0x03
4 00000100 0x04
5 00000101 0x05
6 00000110 0x06
7 00000111 0x07
8 00001000 0x08
9 00001001 0x09
10 00001010 0x0a
```

Answer (score 6):

So I searched for a short and elegant awk binary converter. Not satisfied considered this as a challenge, so here you are. A little bit optimzed for size, so I put a readable version below.

The printf at the end specifies how large the numbers should be. In this case 8 bits.

Is this bad code? Hmm, yeah... it's awk :-)
Does of course not work with very huge numbers.

67 characters long awk code:

```
awk '{r="";a=$1;while(a){r=((a%2)?"1":"0")r;a=int(a/2)}printf"%08d\n",r}'
```

Edit: 55 characters awk code

```
awk '{r="";a=$1;while(a){r=a%2r;a=int(a/2)}printf"%08d\n",r}'
```

Readable version:

```
awk '{r=""                    # initialize result to empty (not 0)
      a=$1                    # get the number
      while(a!=0){            # as long as number still has a value
        r=((a%2)?"1":"0") r   # prepend the modulos2 to the result
        a=int(a/2)            # shift right (integer division by 2)
      }
      printf "%08d\n",r       # print result with fixed width
     }'
```

And the asked one liner with bin and hex

```
awk '{r="";a=$1;while(a){r=a%2r;a=int(a/2)}printf"%08d 0x%02x\n",r,$1}'
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `bc`. Here's a solution using only awk:

- Fetch the `bits2str` function [available in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html)
- Add this minimal script:

  ```
  {
      printf("%s %s %x\n", $1, bits2str($1), $1)
  }
  ```

This produces:

```
$ awk -f awkscr.awk nums 
1 00000001 1
2 00000010 2
3 00000011 3
```

Comment: Although very correct, I need to introduce a function and breake the one-liner requirement. +1 for using awk.

Comment: @splinux Oh, I missed the one-liner requirement, sorry about that. Thanks though, and I hope it helps someone somewhere :-)

Comment: see my answer below with a <80 chars one liner converting numbers to fixed length binary