# replacing some commands in an existing BASH script

Tags: bash, shell, tshark

I have the following script which sends the results of an iwlist scan via OSC:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM_BANKS=20

while [[ "$input" != "\e" ]] ; do

networks=$(iwlist wlan0 scanning | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[:=]"; OFS = " " }
/ESSID/{ 
    #gsub(/ /,"\\ ",$2)
    #gsub(/\"/,"",$2)
    essid[c++]=$2 
}
/Address/{
 gsub(/.*Address: /,"") 
 address[a++]=$0
}
/Encryption key/{ encryption[d++]=$2 }
/Quality/{ 
gsub(/ dBm  /,"")
signal[b++]=$3 
}
END {
for( c in essid ) { print "/wlan_scan ",essid[c],signal[c],encryption[c] }
}' 
)
read -t 0.1  input

echo "$networks" | while read network; do
set $network
hash=` echo "$2" | md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }'| tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` 
bank=`echo "ibase=16;obase=A; $hash%$NUM_BANKS " | bc`
echo "$1$bank $2 $3 $4"
echo "$1$bank $2 $3 $4" | sendOSC -h localhost 9997 
done

#echo "$networks" | sendOSC -h localhost 9997

done
```

An example of the output from this is '/wlan_scan13 BTHomehub757 -85 On', which is then sent via the sendOSC program.

I basically need to replace the iwlist scan data with the results of this tshark scan:

```
sudo tshark -I -i en1 -T fields -e wlan.sa_resolved -e wlan_mgt.ssid -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal type mgt subtype probe
```

which similarly outputs two strings and an int, outputting a result like:

```
'Hewlett-_91:fa:xx  EE-BrightBox-mjmxxx -78'.
```

So eventually I want the script to give me an output in this instance of

```
'/wlan13 Hewlett-_91:fa:xx  EE-BrightBox-mjmxxx -78'.
```

Both scans constantly generate results in this format at about the same rate, updating as new wifi routers are detected, and these are sent out as soon as they arrive over the sendOSC program.

This is probably a pretty simple edit for an experienced coder, but I've been trying to work this out for days and I figured I should ask for help!

If someone could clarify what needs to stay and what needs to go here I'd really appreciate it.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you increase the signal-to-noise ratio of your question and provide sample input and output data, you stand a much better chance of getting help.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but reviewing your history, pluse uno for actually having some code in your question AND for your persistence. But we need some sample `tshark` output and your expected output from that data. Good luck.

Comment: That's good advice, thanks.  I've just edited the post to provide a sample of both the output from the original script and the output from tshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to *replace* commands?  The sane approach would seem to be to add an option to the script to specify which piece of code to run, and include them both.

```
# TODO: replace with proper option parsing
case $1 in
   --tshark) command=tshark_networks; shift;;
   *) command=iwlist_networks;;
esac

tshark_networks () {
   sudo tshark -I -i en1 -T fields \
       -e wlan.sa_resolved \
       -e wlan_mgt.ssid \
       -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal type mgt subtype probe
}

iwlist_networks () {
    iwlist wlan0 scanning | awk .... long Awk script here ....
}


while [[ "$input" != "\e" ]] ; do
    networks=$($command)
    read -t 0.1 input
    echo "$networks" | while read network; do
        : the rest as before, except fix your indentation
```

This also has the nice side effect that the hideous `iwlist` command is encapsulated in its own function, outside of the main loop.

... Well, in fact, I might refactor the main loop to

```
while true; do
    $command |
    while read a b c d; do
        hash=$(echo "$b" | md5sum | awk '{ print toupper($1) }')
        bank=$(echo "ibase=16;obase=A; $hash%$NUM_BANKS " | bc)
        echo "$a$bank $b $c $d"
        echo "$a$bank $b $c $d" | sendOSC -h localhost 9997 
    done
    read -t 0.1 input
    case $input in '\e') break;; esac
done
```

Comment: Putting a function name in a variable is slightly murky but I feel it simplifies the exposition.  You might want to chain a set of functions -- create a function named `command` which switches between the two data generator functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18870379/874188 suggests a way to avoid the funky `bc` and use just Awk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time/effort tripleee - and for the general tidying of the script!  It's actually intended to only run one of those processes, but it's nice to have the option.  Am I reading this right that it's currently defaulting to run tshark_networks part?

Comment: No, the default is `iwlist` and it only changes if it's invoked with an option `--tshark`.

Comment: ah okay, thanks for the clarification.  But are the variables that get printed in with /wlan_scan only being generated by iwlist_networks, and not also by tshark_networks as required?  Apologies if this has an obvious answer, just trying to apply my novice bash knowledge here.

Comment: What variables?  As per your question, I have assumed that the output from your `tshark` command is compatible with the output from `iwlist | awk` so you can just plug in one or the other.